# how to have the first accordion in each section start open, but ALSO behave independently of the other section

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
    //Accordian jQuery
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.accordian-content').hide();
        $(".accordian-content:first").slideDown();
        $('.accordian-title').click(function () {
            const flag = $(this).find('.accordian-title-icon').hasClass('accordian-title-icon-open');
            $('.accordian-title-icon').removeClass('accordian-title-icon-open');
            $('.accordian-content').not($(this).next('.accordian-content')).slideUp();
            $(this).next('.accordian-content').slideToggle();
            if (!flag) {
                $(this).find('.accordian-title-icon').addClass('accordian-title-icon-open')

                //Add this code
               /* thisE = $(this)
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $('html, body').animate({
                        scrollTop: thisE.offset().top -75 }, 'slow');
                }, 450)//Wait for toggle animation to finish */

            } else {
                $(this).find('.accordian-title-icon').removeClass('accordian-title-icon-open')
            }

        });
    });
```

```css
     .priority-lists {width:100%;}
        .accordian-title {
            width: 100%;
            cursor: pointer;
            padding: 20px 10px 20px 20px;
            font-size: 20px;
        }

        .accordian-item {
            color: rgba(40, 150, 211, 1);
            margin: 10px auto;
            width: 100%;
            max-width: 530px;
            background: #fff;
            border: solid 1px #f0f0f0;
            border-radius: 5px;
            -webkit-box-shadow: -4px 4px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.29);
            -moz-box-shadow: -4px 4px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.29);
            box-shadow: -4px 4px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.29);
            -webkit-transition: all .1s ease;
            -moz-transition: all .1s ease;
            -o-transition: all .1s ease;
            transition: all .1s ease;
        }

        .accordian-item:hover {
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
            -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
        }

        .accordian .accordian-item .accordian-title .accordian-title-icon {
            background: #dedede;
            border-radius: 50%;
            width: 25px;
            height: 25px;
            display: inline-block;
            text-align: center;
            color: white;
            font-weight: 700;
            margin-right: 0;
            padding: 0 0 0 1px;
            position: relative;
            vertical-align: top;
            float: right;
            opacity: 1;
            -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
            -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
            -o-transition: all .3s ease;
        }



            .accordian .accordian-item .accordian-title .accordian-title-icon:before {
                content: '+';
                display: block;
                position: absolute;
                width: 100%;
                font-size: 21px;
                line-height: 24px;
                margin: -1px;
            }

        .accordian .accordian-item .accordian-title .accordian-title-icon-open:before {
            display: none;
        }

        .accordian .accordian-item .accordian-title .accordian-title-icon-open:after {
            content: '-';
            margin-top: -3px;
            margin-left: -1px;
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
            text-align: center;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .accordian-content {
            color: #3a3a3a;
            padding: 0 20px 20px;
            text-align: left;
        }

        .accordian-content2 {
            color: #3a3a3a;
            padding: 0 20px 20px;
            text-align: left;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h2>SECTION 2</h2>

<div class="priority-lists">
                <div class="accordian">

                    <div class="accordian-item">
                        <div class="accordian-title">TITLE<span class="accordian-title-icon"></span></div>
                        <div class="accordian-content" style="display: none;">
                            <p>This is a sentence.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="accordian-item">
                        <div class="accordian-title">TITLE<span class="accordian-title-icon"></span></div>
                        <div class="accordian-content" style="display: none;">
                            <p>This is a sentence</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="accordian-item">
                        <div class="accordian-title">TITLE<span class="accordian-title-icon"></span></div>
                        <div class="accordian-content" style="display: none;">
                            <p>this is a sentence</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
                
                <h2>SECTION 2</h2>
                
 <div class="priority-lists">
                <div class="accordian">

                    <div class="accordian-item">
                        <div class="accordian-title">TITLE<span class="accordian-title-icon"></span></div>
                        <div class="accordian-content" style="display: none;">
                            <p>This is a sentence.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="accordian-item">
                        <div class="accordian-title">TITLE<span class="accordian-title-icon"></span></div>
                        <div class="accordian-content" style="display: none;">
                            <p>This is a sentence</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="accordian-item">
                        <div class="accordian-title">TITLE<span class="accordian-title-icon"></span></div>
                        <div class="accordian-content" style="display: none;">
                            <p>this is a sentence</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
```

Im trying to have the first accordion in each section start open, but ALSO behave independently of the other section (ie, when you open close accordion items in one section, the other section is unaffected and vice-versa.

I've added $(".accordian-content:first").slideDown(); and this works but is only applied to the very first one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of close all of the `.accordian-content` elements - you would want to close only those that are part of the current accordion:

```
$(this).parents('.accordian').find('.accordian-content')
```

Here is the fix in your code:

```js
//Accordian jQuery
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.accordian-content').hide();
        $(".accordian .accordian-item:first-child .accordian-content").slideDown();
        $('.accordian-title').click(function () {
            const flag = $(this).find('.accordian-title-icon').hasClass('accordian-title-icon-open');
            $(this).parents('.accordian').find('.accordian-title-icon').removeClass('accordian-title-icon-open');
            $(this).parents('.accordian').find('.accordian-content').not($(this).next('.accordian-content')).slideUp();
            $(this).next('.accordian-content').slideToggle();
            if (!flag) {
                $(this).find('.accordian-title-icon').addClass('accordian-title-icon-open')

                //Add this code
               /* thisE = $(this)
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $('html, body').animate({
                        scrollTop: thisE.offset().top -75 }, 'slow');
                }, 450)//Wait for toggle animation to finish */

            } else {
                $(this).find('.accordian-title-icon').removeClass('accordian-title-icon-open')
            }

        });
    });
```

```css
.priority-lists {width:100%;}
        .accordian-title {
            width: 100%;
            cursor: pointer;
            padding: 20px 10px 20px 20px;
            font-size: 20px;
        }

        .accordian-item {
            color: rgba(40, 150, 211, 1);
            margin: 10px auto;
            width: 100%;
            max-width: 530px;
            background: #fff;
            border: solid 1px #f0f0f0;
            border-radius: 5px;
            -webkit-box-shadow: -4px 4px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.29);
            -moz-box-shadow: -4px 4px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.29);
            box-shadow: -4px 4px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.29);
            -webkit-transition: all .1s ease;
            -moz-transition: all .1s ease;
            -o-transition: all .1s ease;
            transition: all .1s ease;
        }

        .accordian-item:hover {
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
            -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
        }

        .accordian .accordian-item .accordian-title .accordian-title-icon {
            background: #dedede;
            border-radius: 50%;
            width: 25px;
            height: 25px;
            display: inline-block;
            text-align: center;
            color: white;
            font-weight: 700;
            margin-right: 0;
            padding: 0 0 0 1px;
            position: relative;
            vertical-align: top;
            float: right;
            opacity: 1;
            -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
            -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
            -o-transition: all .3s ease;
        }



            .accordian .accordian-item .accordian-title .accordian-title-icon:before {
                content: '+';
                display: block;
                position: absolute;
                width: 100%;
                font-size: 21px;
                line-height: 24px;
                margin: -1px;
            }

        .accordian .accordian-item .accordian-title .accordian-title-icon-open:before {
            display: none;
        }

        .accordian .accordian-item .accordian-title .accordian-title-icon-open:after {
            content: '-';
            margin-top: -3px;
            margin-left: -1px;
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
            text-align: center;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .accordian-content {
            color: #3a3a3a;
            padding: 0 20px 20px;
            text-align: left;
        }

        .accordian-content2 {
            color: #3a3a3a;
            padding: 0 20px 20px;
            text-align: left;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h2>SECTION 2</h2>

<div class="priority-lists">
                <div class="accordian">

                    <div class="accordian-item">
                        <div class="accordian-title">TITLE<span class="accordian-title-icon"></span></div>
                        <div class="accordian-content" style="display: none;">
                            <p>This is a sentence.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="accordian-item">
                        <div class="accordian-title">TITLE<span class="accordian-title-icon"></span></div>
                        <div class="accordian-content" style="display: none;">
                            <p>This is a sentence</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="accordian-item">
                        <div class="accordian-title">TITLE<span class="accordian-title-icon"></span></div>
                        <div class="accordian-content" style="display: none;">
                            <p>this is a sentence</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
                
                <h2>SECTION 2</h2>
                
 <div class="priority-lists">
                <div class="accordian">

                    <div class="accordian-item">
                        <div class="accordian-title">TITLE<span class="accordian-title-icon"></span></div>
                        <div class="accordian-content" style="display: none;">
                            <p>This is a sentence.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="accordian-item">
                        <div class="accordian-title">TITLE<span class="accordian-title-icon"></span></div>
                        <div class="accordian-content" style="display: none;">
                            <p>This is a sentence</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="accordian-item">
                        <div class="accordian-title">TITLE<span class="accordian-title-icon"></span></div>
                        <div class="accordian-content" style="display: none;">
                            <p>this is a sentence</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
```

In order to set the first element in each accordion to be open I used

```
$(".accordian .accordian-item:first-child .accordian-content").slideDown();
```